# Как получить значения всех <td> в массив javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6

вопрос заключается в том, что есть таблица, в которую PHP заносит какие-то значения. Я пытаюсь их вытащить с помощью querySelectorAll в массив, но получаю в ответ undefined. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 while ($company_posts = $statement_3->fetch()) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print_r($company_posts['status']) ?></td>
                            <td class="tabpost-title"><?php print_r($company_posts['title']) ?></td>
                            <td class="tabpost-view" ><?php print_r($company_posts['views']) ?></td>
                            <td><?php print_r($company_posts['likes']) ?></td>
                            <td><?php print_r($company_posts['comment']) ?></td>
                            <form action="scripts/delete_post.php" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php print_r($company_posts['id']) ?>" hidden />
                                <td>
                                    <button>Удалить</button>
                            </form>
                            <button onclick="showDropFlex('pop-wrapperChart')">Статистика</button>
                            <!-- <button>Редактировать</button> -->
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

Цикл создает строки и я по каждой пробегаюсь и с помощью обычного запросы вытаскиваю.

```
let views = [document.querySelectorAll('.tabpost-view').textContent]
```

Comment: [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает статический (не динамический) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), содержащий все найденные элементы документа, которые соответствуют указанному селектору.

Comment: Спасибо! Не мог понять, что приходит не тот массив)

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - вернёт [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), его конвертнём в массив через [спред оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) ([...]), пройдёмся по массиву через [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) вернув в массив значение [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) из каждого `<tr>`;

```js
let views = [...document.querySelectorAll('table tr')].map(tr => tr.textContent);

console.info(views);
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <caption>Таблица размеров обуви</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>Россия</th>
  <th>Великобритания</th>
  <th>Европа</th>
  <th>Длина ступни, см</th>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>34,5</td><td>3,5</td><td>36</td><td>23</td></tr>
 <tr><td>35,5</td><td>4</td><td>36⅔</td><td>23–23,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>36</td><td>4,5</td><td>37⅓</td><td>23,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>36,5</td><td>5</td><td>38</td><td>24</td></tr>
 <tr><td>37</td><td>5,5</td><td>38⅔</td><td>24,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>38</td><td>6</td><td>39⅓</td><td>25</td></tr>
 <tr><td>38,5</td><td>6,5</td><td>40</td><td>25,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>39</td><td>7</td><td>40⅔</td><td>25,5–26</td></tr>
 <tr><td>40</td><td>7,5</td><td>41⅓</td><td>26</td></tr>
 <tr><td>40,5</td><td>8</td><td>42</td><td>26,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>41</td><td>8,5</td><td>42⅔</td><td>27</td></tr>
 <tr><td>42</td><td>9</td><td>43⅓</td><td>27,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>43</td><td>9,5</td><td>44</td><td>28</td></tr>
 <tr><td>43,5</td><td>10</td><td>44⅔</td><td>28–28,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>44</td><td>10,5</td><td>45⅓</td><td>28,5–29</td></tr>
 <tr><td>44,5</td><td>11</td><td>46</td><td>29</td></tr>
 <tr><td>45</td><td>11,5</td><td>46⅔</td><td>29,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>46</td><td>12</td><td>47⅓</td><td>30</td></tr>
 <tr><td>46,5</td><td>12,5</td><td>48</td><td>30,5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>47</td><td>13</td><td>48⅔</td><td>31</td></tr>
 <tr><td>48</td><td>13,5</td><td>49⅓</td><td>31,5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Таблицу взял с [статьи по таблицам](http://htmlbook.ru/html/table) с сайта htmlbook.ru в качестве демо.

Comment: Большая благодарность, я так понял, что существует несколько способов NodeList конвертировать в массив. Array.from тоже должен подойти?

Comment: Есть [несколько вариантов](https://gomakethings.com/converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/#converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array), один из них `.from()`, либо можете взять NodeList и пройтись по нему через `.forEach()`. Если мой ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой (слева, под рейтингом ответа)